# XSD Schema - how to ensure that two simple elements either have values or do not have values together

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

please assist, this is what i want to achieve in validating my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<worker>
    <name>dingo</name>
    <ssn>12345</ssn>
</worker>
```

I want to ensure that the two simple elements 'name' and 'ssn' either have values (as a group) or do not have any value (as a group). They cannot exist individually with a value.

I have to use an XSD schema, so cannot use other options i see suggestions sometimes: Relax NG etc.
I looked into creating a group for elements 'name' and 'ssn' but i am unable to find out how to create a restriction for this group to obtain my condition.

My current XSD file:

```
<xs:complexType name="worker">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" "maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:element name="ssn" type="xs:positiveInteger" minOccurs="0" "maxOccurs="1">
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xs:complexType name="worker">
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string">
    <xs:element name="ssn" type="xs:positiveInteger">
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do

```
<xs:complexType name="worker">
   <xs:group ref="workerGrp" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:group name="workerGrp">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string">
    <xs:element name="ssn" type="xs:positiveInteger">
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

Comment: thanks. I implemented the other solution offered (since it was less LOCs for me!) but will try this out for my education.